# bash script - how to get running process lapsed time and argument

Tags: bash, shell

assuming im running python scripts with arguments like the following:

```
 501  8694  8590   0 11:01PM ttys011    0:02.03 /Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/Resources/Python.app/Contents/MacOS/Python test.py 100 yes
 501  8699  8696   0 11:01PM ttys012    0:01.03 /Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/Resources/Python.app/Contents/MacOS/Python test.py 100 no
```

and now i want to use bash script to extract those two processes that are currently running, and get the amount of time each process has been running and argument yes/no. this is what i have done so far to just extract the time taken for each process:

```
#!/bin/bash

commands=$(ps -ef | grep -v grep | grep "while-file")

var=0
for command in $commands;do
    ((var++))
    if [ $var = 7 ];then
        echo "time taken:$command"
    fi

    if [ $var = 17 ];then
        echo "time taken:$command"
    fi
done
```

but this is not clean. if i happen to have 3 processes running, my code will break

So my questions are:

1. how can i get the amount of time each process has been running. in this case the 1st process has been running for 2mins3sec while the 2nd one is 1min3sec.
2. how can i get the argument yes or no from each line.

**--Edit--**

ok so based on twalberg comment i did this:

```
$ps -ef | grep [w]hile-file.py | awk '{print $7, $NF}'
0:00.00 while-file.py
0:00.02 yes
0:00.03 no
```

how do i ignore the first line: 0:00.00 while-file.py

Comment: Can you launch the python process with the `time` command?

Comment: Which OS do you use?

Comment: hmm sorry im not sure what that means?

Comment: im currently coding in mac osx but will deploy into debian

Comment: `ps -ef | grep [t]est.py | awk '{print $7, $NF}'`? I don't see how your `grep "while-file"` is finding those process entries, though. Perhaps you only partially mangled your script/output...?

Comment: hi twalberg, see edit. i tried ur line of code. it works but im getting the extra first line. how do i ignore the first-line. and could you explain how you get the yes/no??

Comment: `$NF` is the last field on the line, which is `yes` or `no` in your example output. In order to figure out why you have the third line, remove the `| awk ...` bit, and see why `grep` is matching more than expected - you may need to tweak your search pattern...

Comment: sorry for late reply. tks a lot twalberg. =)